# Sudden variable reset

Tags: c++

Problem:
"maxPrint" resets to 0 out of nowhere.
In function "skaitymas" it complies to if, and changes itself to "p" finding the biggest one.

After the function is done, "maxPrint" suddenly becomes 0 again... 
maxPrint is not even used anywhere after that..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
const char duomF[] = "1.txt";
const char rezF[] = "rez1.txt";
const int CMax = 81;

void reset(int SK[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CMax; i++)
    {
        SK[i] = 0;
    }
}

void skaitymas(int SK[], int &n, int &maxPrint)
{
    ifstream df(duomF);
    char temp;
    int tempsk;
    int p;

    df >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        df >> p;
        if (p > maxPrint)
        {
            maxPrint = p;
        }
        cout << p << " " << maxPrint << endl;
        for (int j = CMax - p; j < CMax; j++)
        {
            df >> temp;

            {    if (temp == '0') tempsk = 0;
            else if (temp == '1') tempsk = 1;
            else if (temp == '2') tempsk = 2;
            else if (temp == '3') tempsk = 3;
            else if (temp == '4') tempsk = 4;
            else if (temp == '5') tempsk = 5;
            else if (temp == '6') tempsk = 6;
            else if (temp == '7') tempsk = 7;
            else if (temp == '8') tempsk = 8;
            else if (temp == '9') tempsk = 9;
            }

            SK[j] += tempsk;
        }
    }
    df.close();
}

void skaiciavimas(int SK[])
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = CMax; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(SK[i] >= 10)
        {
            temp = SK[i] / 10;
            SK[i-1] += temp;
            SK[i] = SK[i] % 10;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int SK[CMax];
    int n; int maxPrint = 0;

    reset(SK);
    skaitymas(SK, n, maxPrint);
    skaiciavimas(SK);


    for (int i = CMax - (maxPrint - 1); i < CMax; i++) cout << SK[i] << " ";
    cout << maxPrint << endl;

    ofstream rf(rezF);
    for (int i = CMax - (maxPrint - 1); i < CMax; i++) rf << SK[i];
    rf.close();

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this loop you are accessing `SK` out of bounds:

```
void skaiciavimas(int SK[])
{
    int temp;
    for (int i = CMax; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(SK[i] >= 10)            //<<< BUG (i = CMax)
        {
            temp = SK[i] / 10;     //<<< BUG (i = CMax)
            SK[i-1] += temp;       //<<< BUG (i = 0)
            SK[i] = SK[i] % 10;    //<<< BUG (i = CMax)
        }
    }
}
```

Note that valid indices for `SK` are from `0` to `CMax - 1`, so accessing `SK[CMax]` results in undefined behaviour, as does accessing `SK[-1]`.

Note that when you write to an array out of bounds you may well overwrite adjacent variables, which probably explains the unexpected modification of `maxPrint`, but as with any case of undefined behaviour, literally anything can happen.

Without knowing what your code is supposed be doing I can only guess that perhaps your for loop should be:

```
for (int i = CMax - 1; i > 0; i--)
```

Comment: Yep. Undefined behaviour. Luckily, no cats were set on fire. This time.

Comment: I have no idea how this had any effect on a variable thats not even there ;...; But thanks. Now it works.

Comment: @xTheEc0: see edit - when you write to an array out of bounds you may well overwrite adjacent variables.

Comment: You may well overwrite adjacent variables... or anything else!  In theory, it could be program code, OS code, hard drive space, the US Constitution.   Undefined Behavior means ["Anything can happen"](http://i123.photobucket.com/albums/o313/kasiopeia/thursday3.png)